# Create new directory to forcefully replace the old one in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I am trying to create the directory in ruby on rails.

I have succeeded to create the directory using `FileUtils.mkdir()`, but I need to create the directory so that the newly created directory replace the old one.

I have searched a lot on google and also study the docs of `FileUtils` but could not find to achieve this.

Is there any way to get it done?

Comment: What do you mean replace the old one? There is an existing directory with the same name? Why not just delete the contents of the existing one then?

Comment: You may want to check ownership of the root folder that the directory is being made in and make sure that it has access to create a new directory.

Comment: @ndn I have implemented this thing already. Delete the old one and create the new one but I have integrated angular with ruby on rails and when i create the file by clicking the button first time it delete old one and creates new one but on the second time pressing the button it gives me the file existing error. If i refresh the page and then try again then first time old one delete and new one created.

Comment: Then it seems you remove the old one only after the first click. Remove it any time you intend to create it.

Comment: I have implemented the condition in the controller that if the directory exists then delete it and then create new one . Else create directly the new directory and this code execute each time .But i don't know why this code is not working for the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not delete the directory and then create it again:

```
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.rm_rf('directorypath/name')
```

or

```
FileUtils.remove_dir(somedir)
```

Comment: I have implemented this thing already. Delete the old one and create the new one but I have integrated angular with ruby on rails and when i create the file by clicking the button first time it delete old one and creates new one but on the second time pressing the button it gives me the file existing error. If i refresh the page and then try again then first time old one delete and new one created and so on.

Comment: it looks like a javascript request problem, were you having to reload the page, look into ajax to preform this action?

Comment: I am using coffee script to call the controller using ajax request. I don't want to reload my page as this app is using angular.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in FileUtils not such thing as `recreate directory`. But you delete and create dir:

```
FileUtils.rmdir('your_dir')
FileUtils.mkdir('your_dir')
```

You may all available functions to handle directories in [FileUtils module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html) and [Dir class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Dir.html).

Comment: I have implemented this thing already. Delete the old one and create the new one but I have integrated angular with ruby on rails and when i create the file by clicking the button first time it delete old one and creates new one but on the second time pressing the button it gives me the file existing error. If i refresh the page and then try again then first time old one delete and new one created and so on

Comment: It's difficult to say without details about your application